# Адаптивные ряды и строки в CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На большом экране у меня должно 6 элеметов в ряд, а на мобильных экранах по одному элементу, но выводится по другому. Как мне исправить данный код?

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <div class="container row" align="center">
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
    <img style="width:100px" src="../aptis.png?2"/><br>

</li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
  <img style="width:100px" src="../bio.png?2"/>

</li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
    <img style="width:100px" src="../think.png?2"/><br>

</li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
    <img style="width:100px" src="../math.png?2"/><br>
</li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
    <img style="width:100px" src="../phys.png?2"/><br>
</li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" align="center">
<li class="dropdown-top">
    <img style="width:100px" src="../chem.png?2"/><br>
</li>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Медиа запросы пробовал использовать?

Comment: @spais нет, а через готовые классы Bootstrap нельзя это сделать?

Comment: если можешь делай

Comment: Есть готовые классы в фреймворке или для контейнера в медиа запросах для мобильных flex-direction: column

Comment: @Netahaki спасибо. воспользовался предложенным вами `flex-direction: column`